# color changing background won't change color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a code for a game which requires a flashing background of random colors making use of Math.floor(), Math.random(), and arrays to create random hex codes. I want the background to change color every 1 second, but the color doesn't even show up in the first place. Here's my code;

```
<script>
var a = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f"];
var b = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f"];
var c = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f"];
var d = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f"];
var e = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f"];
var f = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f"];

var A;
var B;
var C;
var D;
var E;
var F;

setInterval(function(){
A = a[Math.floor(Math.random()*a.length)];
B = b[Math.floor(Math.random()*b.length)];
C = c[Math.floor(Math.random()*c.length)];
D = d[Math.floor(Math.random()*d.length)];
E = e[Math.floor(Math.random()*e.length)];
F = f[Math.floor(Math.random()*f.length)];
},1000);

document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#"+A+B+C+D+E+F;
</script>
```

If anyone could help, that would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#"+A+B+C+D+E+F;
```

should go inside your `setInterval`

I.e.

```
setInterval(function() {
  A = a[Math.floor(Math.random()*a.length)];
  B = b[Math.floor(Math.random()*b.length)];
  C = c[Math.floor(Math.random()*c.length)];
  D = d[Math.floor(Math.random()*d.length)];
  E = e[Math.floor(Math.random()*e.length)];
  F = f[Math.floor(Math.random()*f.length)];
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#"+A+B+C+D+E+F;
},1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access variables A, B, C, D, E, F inside your setInterval function, try this:

```js
var a = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f"];
var b = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f"];
var c = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f"];
var d = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f"];
var e = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f"];
var f = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f"];



setInterval(function(){
    let A = a[Math.floor(Math.random()* a.length)];
    let B = b[Math.floor(Math.random()* b.length)];
    let C = c[Math.floor(Math.random()* c.length)];
    let D = d[Math.floor(Math.random()* d.length)];
    let E = e[Math.floor(Math.random()* e.length)];
    let F = f[Math.floor(Math.random()* f.length)];
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = '#' + A + B + C + D + E + F; 
}, 1000);
```